# Want to create a score for a column in dataframe in python using the sum of actual position and Alphabetical position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a string column in a dataframe like this. 
`raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Aravind', 'Netaji', 'Swamiji', 'Ramakrishna', 'Jake']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name'])`

I want to create a score for each cell, the definition of the score is as follows:
score for Jason is=(1*10 + 2*1 + 3*19 + 4*15 + 5*14)= 199.
Similarly, for ABc the score will be (1*1+2*2+3*3)=14

I created different columns fro each letter using the below code:

```
df['len']=df['first_name'].str.len()
l=df['len'].max()
for i in range(0,l):
    df[i+1]=df.first_name.str[i]
```

and also found out using ord() as follows we can get the position also

```
a = 'Arun'
a=a.lower()
i= 1
for char in a:
   asc = ord(char)-96
   print(char,asc, i, asc*i)
   i = i+1
```

But not able to apply it in case of a dataframe, can anybody help me to create the score in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with custom function and list comprehension:

```
def f(x):
    return sum(i * (ord(char) - 96) for i, char in enumerate(x, 1))

df['new'] = df['first_name'].str.lower().apply(f)
print(df)
    first_name  new
0        Jason  199
1      Aravind  285
2       Netaji  192
3      Swamiji  288
4  Ramakrishna  664
5         Jake   65
```

List comprehension solution:

```
a = [sum(i * (ord(char) - 96) for i, char in enumerate(x, 1))
     for x in df['first_name'].str.lower()]
print(a)
[199, 285, 192, 288, 664, 65]

df['new'] = a
print(df)
    first_name  new
0        Jason  199
1      Aravind  285
2       Netaji  192
3      Swamiji  288
4  Ramakrishna  664
5         Jake   65
```

Comment: Don't need `list(x)`, `x` should do.

Comment: If you want to give a name to a function, please use `def f(x): ...`.  It is the idiomatic way of defining functions in Python, and also associates the name with the function objects, so you get much more readable tracebacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven.

Comment: Hi John and jezrael: Have another question regarding the same. I have created a lot of columns in the form pos1 pos2 pos3 to pos100 having the positions of the letters in the alphabet. But in the output df the columns are not ordered. like pos2 comes pos10 like that. Is there any automated way to retain the column names in the order pos1 to pos100?

Comment: Hmmm, I think the best is create numeric columns only if possible.  Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('\d+', expand=False).astype(int)` and then sort columns by `df= df.sort_index(axis=1)`. I am on phone only, so untested.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
In [783]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [784]: score = lambda x: sum(i*(ascii_lowercase.index(l)+1) for i, l in enumerate(x, 1))

In [785]: df.first_name.str.lower().apply(score)
Out[785]:
0    199
1    285
2    192
3    288
4    664
5     65
Name: first_name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase.index()` performs a linear search for the character in the string of lower-case characters, which seems rather wasteful.  You also don't need the square brackets, and I'd suggest to move the score function to an actual named function instead of cramming everything into one line.

Comment: Thanks, overseen it, `ord` should be the right way here.